# My first XML written in .NET is giving me problems with the structure

Tags: .net, xml, database, vb.net, database-design

I need help with an XML structure because I'm totally newbie with XML so I could be wrong to design the structure for later read in VB.NET.

(This is like the 4th question I do about this... but is not a duplicated, please be comprehensive about that, I'm taking this seriously to do this by my own merits, I'm bored of writing the same thing about this topic.)

In an application I would like to be able to manage my collection of music, right now I have a lot of text-files (239 files) titled like these:

```
90's Dance
2006 Electro
2007 Hardstyle
2013 Pop (English)
2013 Rock (English)
2013 UK Hardcore
```

As you see are delimited by `Year Musicstyle.txt`

Well, each file contains data like this:

```
Ab - Stay With Me;320;05:53;13,54
Above & Beyond Feat. Richard Bedford - Sun & Moon (Reaktor Hardcore Remix);320;06:03;13,87
Adrenalin - No Need To Run;320;06:07;14,04
Afrojack & Steve Aoki Feat. Miss Palmer - No Beef (Nobody Bootleg);320;05:45;13,19
Andy Wilson - Forever Loved;192;05:45;7,89
```

As you see are delimited by `Filename;Bitrate;Duration;SizeInMegabytes`

Many people from SO said me that the best is to create a database in SQL or XML, and this is what I try since SQL seems a littler hard to start learnning, I don't know anything about XML or SQL.

Well you can see the structure what I need for my XML file, the xml file need to be separated by `Year` and then `MusicStyle`, and there I will put the songs information.

I've read a tutorial to write xml files in VB.NET but the final structure what I got looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Songs Database.-->
<Songs>
  <_2013>
    <Rock>
      <FileName>My Song 1.mp3</FileName>
      <Bitrate>320</Bitrate>
      <Duration>04:55</Duration>
      <Filesize>4,80</Filesize>
      <FileName>My Song 2.mp3</FileName>
      <Bitrate>192</Bitrate>
      <Duration>06:44</Duration>
      <Filesize>8,43</Filesize>
      <FileName>My Song 3.mp3</FileName>
      <Bitrate>128</Bitrate>
      <Duration>05:12</Duration>
      <Filesize>4,20</Filesize>
      <FileName>My Song 4.mp3</FileName>
      <Bitrate>256</Bitrate>
      <Duration>07:32</Duration>
      <Filesize>9,51</Filesize>
    </Rock>
  </_2013>
</Songs>
```

But I think that structure is not correct, I don't know but would not be better and easier to read an structure like this else?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Songs Database.-->
<Songs>
  <_2013>
    <Rock>
      <FileName>My Song 1.mp3</FileName><Bitrate>320</Bitrate><Duration>04:55</Duration><Filesize>4,80</Filesize>
      <FileName>My Song 2.mp3</FileName><Bitrate>192</Bitrate><Duration>06:44</Duration><Filesize>8,43</Filesize>
      <FileName>My Song 3.mp3</FileName><Bitrate>128</Bitrate><Duration>05:12</Duration><Filesize>4,20</Filesize>
      <FileName>My Song 4.mp3</FileName><Bitrate>256</Bitrate><Duration>07:32</Duration><Filesize>9,51</Filesize>
    </Rock>
  </_2013>
</Songs>
```

The problems are:

1. I'm not sure which would be the best structure design for my database requeriments.
2. I don't know exactly how to do design it, so I need help to fix the code and also the design.
3. I've tried it but I cannot write the second kind of structure (that which I said that it seemed easier to read)

This is the code that I'm using to write the first structure kind:

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1

    ' lets create the MyXML.xml document,
    Dim xmlfile As String = "c:\MyXML.xml"

    ' declare our xmlwriter object
    Dim Xml As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(xmlfile, _
                              New XmlWriterSettings() With {.Indent = True})

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown

        ' Write the Xml declaration.
        Write_Start(Xml)

        ' Write a comment.
        Write_Comment(Xml, "XML Songs Database.")

        ' Write the root element.
        Write_Element(Xml, "Songs")

        ' Start our first year element.
        Write_Element(Xml, "_2013")

        ' Start our first music style.
        Xml.WriteStartElement("Rock")

        ' The music style song nodes:
        Write_SongInfo_Node(Xml, "My Song 1.mp3", "320", "04:55", "4,80")
        Write_SongInfo_Node(Xml, "My Song 2.mp3", "192", "06:44", "8,43")
        Write_SongInfo_Node(Xml, "My Song 3.mp3", "128", "05:12", "4,20")
        Write_SongInfo_Node(Xml, "My Song 4.mp3", "256", "07:32", "9,51")

        ' Write the xml end
        Write_End(Xml)

        ' Start the file and exit
        Process.Start(xmlfile) : Application.Exit()

    End Sub


    Private Sub Write_Start(ByVal xml As XmlWriter)
        Xml.WriteStartDocument()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Write_Comment(ByVal xml As XmlWriter, ByVal Comment As String)
        xml.WriteComment(Comment)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Write_Element(ByVal xml As XmlWriter, ByVal element As String)
        xml.WriteStartElement(element)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Write_SongInfo_Node(ByVal xml As XmlWriter,
                      ByVal Filename As String, _
                      ByVal Bitrate As String, _
                      ByVal Duration As String, _
                      ByVal Filesize As String)

        xml.WriteStartElement("FileName")
        xml.WriteString(Filename)
        xml.WriteEndElement()

        xml.WriteStartElement("Bitrate")
        xml.WriteString(Bitrate)
        xml.WriteEndElement()

        xml.WriteStartElement("Duration")
        xml.WriteString(Duration)
        xml.WriteEndElement()

        xml.WriteStartElement("Filesize")
        xml.WriteString(Filesize)
        xml.WriteEndElement()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Write_End(ByVal xml As XmlWriter)
        xml.WriteEndDocument()
        xml.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

> UPDATE:

I'm getting this indentation formatting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Songs Database.-->
<Songs>
  <Song>
    <FileName>My Song 1.mp3</FileName>
    <Year>2007</Year>
    <Genre>Dance</Genre>
    <Bitrate>320</Bitrate>
    <Duration>04:55</Duration>
    <Filesize>4,80</Filesize>
  </Song>
  <Song>
    <FileName>My Song 2.mp3</FileName>
    <Year>2009</Year>
    <Genre>Electro</Genre>
    <Bitrate>192</Bitrate>
    <Duration>06:44</Duration>
    <Filesize>8,43</Filesize>
  </Song>
  <Song>
    <FileName>My Song 3.mp3</FileName>
    <Year>2008</Year>
    <Genre>UK Hardcore</Genre>
    <Bitrate>128</Bitrate>
    <Duration>05:12</Duration>
    <Filesize>4,20</Filesize>
  </Song>
  <Song>
    <FileName>My Song 4.mp3</FileName>
    <Year>2013</Year>
    <Genre>Techno</Genre>
    <Bitrate>256</Bitrate>
    <Duration>07:32</Duration>
    <Filesize>9,51</Filesize>
  </Song>
</Songs>
```

But I want this formatting to save amount of "space" characters and then save file size:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Songs Database.-->
<Songs>
  <Song><FileName>My Song 1.mp3</FileName><Year>2007</Year><Genre>Dance</Genre><Bitrate>320</Bitrate><Duration>04:55</Duration><Filesize>4,80</Filesize></Song>
  <Song><FileName>My Song 2.mp3</FileName><Year>2009</Year><Genre>Electro</Genre><Bitrate>192</Bitrate><Duration>06:44</Duration><Filesize>8,43</Filesize></Song>
  <Song><FileName>My Song 3.mp3</FileName><Year>2008</Year><Genre>UK Hardcore</Genre><Bitrate>128</Bitrate><Duration>05:12</Duration><Filesize>4,20</Filesize></Song>
  <Song><FileName>My Song 4.mp3</FileName><Year>2013</Year><Genre>Techno</Genre><Bitrate>256</Bitrate><Duration>07:32</Duration><Filesize>9,51</Filesize></Song>
</Songs>
```

This is what I'm trying:

```vb
Private Sub Write_SongInfo_Node(ByVal xml As XmlWriter,
                  ByVal Filename As String, _
                  ByVal Year As String, _
                  ByVal Genre As String, _
                  ByVal Bitrate As String, _
                  ByVal Duration As String, _
                  ByVal Filesize As String)

    xml.WriteStartElement("Song")

    ' xml.Settings.Indent = False

    xml.WriteStartElement("FileName")
    xml.WriteString(Filename)
    xml.WriteEndElement()

    xml.WriteStartElement("Year")
    xml.WriteString(Year)
    xml.WriteEndElement()

    xml.WriteStartElement("Genre")
    xml.WriteString(Genre)
    xml.WriteEndElement()

    xml.WriteStartElement("Bitrate")
    xml.WriteString(Bitrate)
    xml.WriteEndElement()

    xml.WriteStartElement("Duration")
    xml.WriteString(Duration)
    xml.WriteEndElement()

    xml.WriteStartElement("Filesize")
    xml.WriteString(Filesize)
    xml.WriteEndElement()

    '  xml.Settings.Indent = True

    xml.WriteEndElement()

End Sub
```

Comment: Those two XML examples look identical. Can you highlight what's different between them (bearing in mind that XML is *not* just a string)

Comment: the difference is one is full indented but the other is not, I think indentation is part of that we call "structure", thanks for comment!

Comment: Indentation has no meaning in XML. Structure is provided by elements.

Comment: Indentation is irrelevant - both documents convey the same *information*. If you want to group several elements together (as you seem to be attempting with indentation) you would place them within another element - as per `<Song>` in CodeCaster's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in your XML examples, apart from some newlines. You'll need to stick each song in a `Song` element, so your XML becomes:

```
<Rock>
    <Song>
        <FileName> [..]</Filesize>
    </Song>
    <Song>
        <FileName> [..]</Filesize>
    </Song>
    [..]
<Rock>
```

That being said, I wouldn't group your files on year or category. Those are again properties of the song.

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion, I'm trying to do it like you've suggested, but I don't get the desired formatting, could you see my update to help me to resolve it?

Comment: @ElektroStudios I'm afraid the XmlWriter doesn't offer that much control on how your data is indented. It's kind of an "all or nothing" setting. Please note whitespace outside of values has no meaning in XML.

Comment: Setting the Indent to False and then using `xml.WriteString(Environment.NewLine)` at certain lines it works, thanks again.

Comment: I've found a better way, using a `XmlTextWriter` instead of a `XmlWriter` I'm able to change the Indent property when object is instanced (using the `XmlWriter` is not possibly to change it)